# How to prepare Container for one writer and multiple reader using Semaphore?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, semaphore

My problem is pretty simple... I have a singleton Container which should pass Data between threads. There are multiple Threads reading data out of this Container, but only one is writing in it. My ideal solution would be, if the reading threads could only read when there is new data.
My idea is that the readers use the Semaphore to block them self and the writer releases the data to read after he updated it. But how do I realize that with more than one reading thread?

this is what I got so far, not much I know but I got stuck.

```java
public class Container {

  String string ="";
  int inteter;

  private Semaphore mySemapore = new Semaphore(0);

  private static final Container ourInstance = new Container();

  public synchronized static Container getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
  }

  private Container() {
  }

  public void setString(String setstring){

    string = setstring;
  }


  public String getString(){
    return string;
  }


}
```

Comment: Why `Semaphore`? This is an obvious case for `ReadWriteLock`.

Comment: I'm used to it through other languages, but thanks for this advice, I will do a research. Btw. I found my solution. I will post it as soon as i'm allowed, I would be happy if you tell me your thoughts about my solution.

Comment: I would be astonished if your solution consisted in anything other than what I've already stated, an if it does it is almost certainly not a solution at all, or else a mere reimplementation of `ReadWriteLock`.

Comment: @user207421 check my answer.

Answer (score -1):

My solution provides a fair semaphore.

```java
public class Container {

  private String string;
  private int inteter= -1;

  private Semaphore mySemapore = new Semaphore(2, true);

  private static final Container ourInstance = new Container();

  public synchronized static Container getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
  }

  private Container() {
  }

  public void release(){
    mySemapore.release(2);
  }

  public void setString(String setstring){
    string = setstring;
  }

  public void setInteter(int inteter){
    this.inteter = inteter;
  }

  public Bundle getBundle(){
    try {
      mySemapore.acquire(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("String", string);
    bundle.putInt("integer", inteter);
    return bundle;
  }
}
```

`release()` is called by the writer thread.

My output is that two threads always read the same value once, till the write releases it again.